# javascript : Error for increment seconds

Tags: javascript, date, time, clock, seconds

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var st = "January 19, 2017 18:33:31" 
    var today = new Date(st);
    var montharray = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ogu","Sep","Oct","Nov","Des");
    var h = today.getHours();
    var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12;
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    h = checkTime(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    checkTime(today.getDate())+" "+montharray[today.getMonth()]+" "+today.getFullYear() + " (" + ampm +" " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s +")"; 
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="startTime();">
    <span id="txt"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to auto increment the seconds.
I know that if I am  using

```
var today = new Date();
```

Instead of this,

```
var st = "January 19, 2017 18:33:31" 
        var today = new Date(st);
```

it will be executed successfully.but i don't want that.I need the
 output based on the code written above.

Thanks

Comment: I dont see any approach to.increase the time

Comment: I need a solution otherwise i cant continue my project.One of the famous quote that **"If there is a question,there must be a solution"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification for startTime

```
var st = "January 19, 2017 18:33:31";
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date(st);
    var montharray = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ogu","Sep","Oct","Nov","Des");
    var h = today.getHours();
    var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12;
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    h = checkTime(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    checkTime(today.getDate())+" "+montharray[today.getMonth()]+" "+today.getFullYear() + " (" + ampm +" " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s +")"; 
    today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 1);
    st = today;
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/1btotz3a/

Comment: u done a great thing.but firstly I am asking sorry for u because the **var st** value get from a html code and also I'm calling the function into body.So i need to declare the value inside the for loop.I think u r confused so I am giving some more details below  `<body onLoad="startTime()"> <input type="hidden" id="vars" value="{% now "F j, Y H:i:s" %}">span id="txt" ></span></body>` this is the html page.and the js script i am getting the value through `var st = document.getElementById('vars').value;` this is the way i am set the value to st variable.Now i think u r cleared.

Comment: so I cant declare the variable **st** before the function.so please help me .Thanks

Comment: put the script to the bottom of the file so you can declare var st outside of the function ( after the body tag ) If I help you, please approve this answer

Comment: yes of course.but can u give me a detailed solution.I edit your answer but i didn't get solution.please help me

Comment: i have write the script to the bottom of the file

Comment: Look at the updated example https://jsfiddle.net/1btotz3a/, you can use getElementById and increase date too

Comment: This is my master page.how can I get this value into another html page

Comment: Idea is the same, put the script after all of the markup so document.getElement* can 100% find an element

Comment: @AlexeyShakura I tried this but It will not work.and also don't know how to take.Can u give an explanation